# Running a SELECT Query with an Ansible Task

Tags: mysql, ansible

In [this](http://docs.ansible.com/list_of_database_modules.html) list of mysql db modules for Ansbile, there's one for creating a db, or creating a user, etc.

I would like to run a query against a pre-existing table and use the results of that query to populate an Ansible variable (list of IP addresses, and node type) upon which I would run different tasks, depending on node type.

How can that be done in Ansible?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is approximately how to do it (but it is untested):

```
- name: Retrieve stuff from mysql
  command: >
    mysql --user=alice --password=topsecret dbname
    --host=147.102.160.1 --batch --skip-column-names
    --execute="SELECT stuff from stuff_table"
  register: stuff
  check_mode: no
  changed_when: False

- name: Do something with stuff
  debug: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: stuff.stdout_lines
```

Documented [here](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html#register-variables).

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing with mssql(sql server) module?

Comment: @user405458 maybe if you replace the command (and config the sqlcmd on the server):

command: > 
   sqlcmd -S 147.102.160.1,49399 -U alice -P topsecret -d dbname -Q "SELECT TOP 5 Id FROM dbo.MyTable;"

[...]

Or with installed mssql-cli ..

Comment: I believe you need neither the `always_run` nor the `changed_when`.  Also, if I remember correctly, at least one of those is deprecated.

Comment: @colan `always_run: yes` has been replaced with `check_mode: no`; I updated the answer with this. It will generally work without `check_mode: no` and `changed_when: False`; however, it won't run correctly with `--check` if you don't have `check_mode: no`, and it will report the task as always changed if you don't have `changed_when: False`. When you run a playbook on a server that is already setup you want it to report that nothing changed.

Comment: Hi @AntonisChristofides if I want to execute multiple sql queries? do I need to repeat "command: >
    mysql --user=alice --password=topsecret dbname
    --host=147.102.160.1 --batch --skip-column-names
    --execute="SELECT stuff from stuff_table" multiple times?

Comment: @Techiescorner We'd need to see the particular use case.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides for example I want to run a select query then I want to run an insert query, in that time I have to include the below command multiple times? "mysql --user=alice --password=topsecret dbname
    --host=147.102.160.1 --batch --skip-column-names
    --execute="