# Is there any way to connect mysql server using ansible and perform operations like execute .sql files and various lind of mysql dump and restore?

Tags: mysql, ansible

I am trying to connect mysql db using ansible but unable to login, how can I able to connect my mysql database using ansible and do operation like database dump- data restoration and .sql file execution.

Comment: You should consider writing proper client application or script (python, php or perl) to extract your data and load into MySQL db.

Answer (score 0):

you can just run it as a shell command in ansible:

```
mysql -u USER -p PASSWORD -h MYSQLSERVERNAME -e 'select * from foo...' database-name

mysql -u USER -p PASSWORD -h MYSQLSERVERNAME database-name < database_name.sql
```

see [here, similar question with playbook snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605950/running-a-select-query-with-an-ansible-task)