# How to access and process the text from a table using Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have to access a particular value from the table, shown below, of data, in an Ansible playbook. I have to use the accessed value in a conditional statement to draw some conclusions based on the value.

For example, the source, whose name is mentioned in the first column of the table:

- is active if the values in the `Average` column is greater than zero
- is inactive, otherwise

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------  
Counter Source | Counter Name    |  Unit |   Min |   Max | Average |  Last   
---------------+-----------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+-------  
Source1        | GC1             |     % |  3.00 | 22.00 |    3.01 |  3.00   
Source2        | GC2             |     % |  2.00 |  7.00 |    2.95 |  3.00   
Source3        | GC3             |     % |  2.00 | 12.00 |    3.00 |  3.00   
Source4        | GC4             |     % | 15.00 | 16.00 |   15.22 | 15.00   
Source5        | GC5             |     % | 39.00 | 44.00 |   41.32 | 43.00   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can someone let me know the way this can be done on Ansible?

Comment: it s difficult to understant where are your datas? in a file; in different variables...?   could you show the playbook you have tried?

Comment: Instead of trying to mingle with human readable formatted data, are you 1000% sure you cannot make whatever is the source of the data output you a machine readable format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a SELECT Query with an Ansible Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605950/running-a-select-query-with-an-ansible-task)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your content is defined in file *file.txt*: (I have just modified the `Source4` average to have a data `inactive`)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------  
Counter Source | Counter Name    |  Unit |   Min |   Max | Average |  Last   
---------------+-----------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+-------  
Source1        | GC1             |     % |  3.00 | 22.00 |    3.01 |  3.00   
Source2        | GC2             |     % |  2.00 |  7.00 |    2.95 |  3.00   
Source3        | GC3             |     % |  2.00 | 12.00 |    3.00 |  3.00   
Source4        | GC4             |     % | 15.00 | 16.00 |    0.00 | 15.00   
Source5        | GC5             |     % | 39.00 | 44.00 |   41.32 | 43.00   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the playbook:

```
- name: "tips1"
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "the source {{ _s }}  is {{ 'active' if _av|float > 0.00 else 'inactive'}}"   
      loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'file.txt').splitlines() }}"
      vars:
        arr: "{{ item.split('|')|list}}"
        _s: "{{ arr[0]|trim }}"
        _av: "{{ arr[5]|trim|float }}"
      when: '"%" in item'
```

result:

```
skipping: [localhost] => (item=---------------------------------------------------------------------------  ) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=Counter Source | Counter Name    |  Unit |   Min |   Max | Average |  Last   ) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=---------------+-----------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+-------  ) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=Source1        | GC1             |     % |  3.00 | 22.00 |    3.01 |  3.00   ) => {
    "msg": "the source Source1  is active"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Source2        | GC2             |     % |  2.00 |  7.00 |    2.95 |  3.00   ) => {
    "msg": "the source Source2  is active"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Source3        | GC3             |     % |  2.00 | 12.00 |    3.00 |  3.00   ) => {
    "msg": "the source Source3  is active"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Source4        | GC4             |     % | 15.00 | 16.00 |    0.00 | 15.00   ) => {
    "msg": "the source Source4  is inactive"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Source5        | GC5             |     % | 39.00 | 44.00 |   41.32 | 43.00   ) => {
    "msg": "the source Source5  is active"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=-----------------------------------------------------------------------------)
```

to avoid the `when`, you could use the tip proposed by @β.εηοιτ.βε,

```
loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'file.txt').splitlines()[3:-1] }}"
```

Comment: I did a similar trial my side, and most was the same as you proposed. The only thing that could still unclutter the output a bit would be to do `loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'file.txt').splitlines()[3:-1] }}"`, which would get the table 'header' and 'footer' out of the way.

Comment: yes good idea, that replaces the when!!

Answer (score 1):

Given the table

```
table:
  - '---------------------------------------------------------------------------  '
  - 'Counter Source | Counter Name    |  Unit |   Min |   Max | Average |  Last   '
  - '---------------+-----------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+-------  '
  - 'Source1        | GC1             |     % |  3.00 | 22.00 |    3.01 |  3.00   '
  - 'Source2        | GC2             |     % |  2.00 |  7.00 |    2.95 |  3.00   '
  - 'Source3        | GC3             |     % |  2.00 | 12.00 |    3.00 |  3.00   '
  - 'Source4        | GC4             |     % | 15.00 | 16.00 |   15.22 | 15.00   '
  - 'Source5        | GC5             |     % | 39.00 | 44.00 |   41.32 | 43.00   '
  - '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

created, for example, by the evaluation of the lookup plugin

```yaml
table: "{{ lookup('file', 'file.txt').splitlines() }}"
```

---

Put the declarations below as [appropriate](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). Select the keys and values, and create the list of the dictionaries

```yaml
table_keys: "{{ table[1]|split('|')|map('trim')|list }}"
table_vals: "{{ table[3:-1]|map('split', '|')|map('map', 'trim')|list }}"
table_list: "{{ table_vals|map('zip', table_keys)|
                           map('map', 'reverse')|
                           map('community.general.dict') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
table_list:
  - Average: '3.01'
    Counter Name: GC1
    Counter Source: Source1
    Last: '3.00'
    Max: '22.00'
    Min: '3.00'
    Unit: '%'
  - Average: '2.95'
    Counter Name: GC2
    Counter Source: Source2
    Last: '3.00'
    Max: '7.00'
    Min: '2.00'
    Unit: '%'
  - Average: '3.00'
    Counter Name: GC3
    Counter Source: Source3
    Last: '3.00'
    Max: '12.00'
    Min: '2.00'
    Unit: '%'
  - Average: '15.22'
    Counter Name: GC4
    Counter Source: Source4
    Last: '15.00'
    Max: '16.00'
    Min: '15.00'
    Unit: '%'
  - Average: '41.32'
    Counter Name: GC5
    Counter Source: Source5
    Last: '43.00'
    Max: '44.00'
    Min: '39.00'
    Unit: '%'
```

Then, select from the list what you want. For example, select 'Counter Name' for items where 'Average' is greater than 3.0

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: name_average_3
      vars:
        name_average_3: "{{ table_list|json_query(_query) }}"
        _query: '[?to_number(Average) > `3.0`]."Counter Name"'
```

gives

```yaml
name_average_3:
  - GC1
  - GC4
  - GC5
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    table: "{{ lookup('file', 'file.txt').splitlines() }}"
    table_keys: "{{ table[1]|split('|')|map('trim')|list }}"
    table_vals: "{{ table[3:-1]|map('split', '|')|map('map', 'trim')|list }}"
    table_list: "{{ table_vals|map('zip', table_keys)|
                               map('map', 'reverse')|
                               map('community.general.dict') }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: name_average_3
      vars:
        name_average_3: "{{ table_list|json_query(_query) }}"
        _query: '[?to_number(Average) > `3.0`]."Counter Name"'
```